# Can a standard 16.04 user ever make su commands?

Tags: 16.04, sudo, administrator

It happens that I must install new programs while logged in as a standard user who is not a sudoer. Then I must log in as another user from the GNOME login display which is somewhat cumbersome.

Is there another way to do it?

If I'm logged in as a standard user not in the sudoer group, it seems impossible to make `sudo` commands. I tried with `pkexec` and everything, but the only way I can do `sudo` is to log in as the sudo user.

Comment: You have to add that user to the `sudo group` so it can run root commands, or switch to sudo user with `su - username`.

Comment: Are you saying that you are trying to admin your system from a non-admin account? If so, why?

Comment: GUI prompt's _(pkexec)_ can handle selecting another account, if terminal is imperative maybe your best bet is @albertj answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't mind using the command line then it is easy. For example, let's say you have the users Jane and Jim on your computer. Jane has sudo rights, and Jim has not. You are currently logged in as Jim, using the desktop environment.

Open a terminal and type :

```
su - jane
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install some-program another-program
exit
```