# Install a program for another non-sudo user as a sudo user

Tags: software-installation, sudo, authentication

I would like to know how to install something for another user that has no sudo as a sudo user without knowing its password.

That's it, I have a sudo user and I need to install something for a non-sudo user in which I don't know its password.

This is a case in which I am the only user that has sudo in some machine and the other users needs my permission for installing software.

I would like to know the best way to manage that.

Comment: You can't install software _for_ a user, software is installed globally.

Comment: I meant installing locally for another user.

Comment: Which installation mechanism does that software use? If it is not globally installed (e.g. for all users), the user can install it in home directory without any permissions. If it's globally available... well, install it.

Comment: What kind of software? Is it from Ubuntu repos?

Comment: You could use Flatpak to install a program that only a specific user could run, or you could download a pre-compiled tarball and install it in a user's home directory.

Comment: I think I did a very general question. Can I use my root privilege to run a command as another user?

Comment: You mean like `sudo -Hu otheruser`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a standard 16.04 user ever make su commands?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879905/can-a-standard-16-04-user-ever-make-su-commands)

Answer (score 2):

Sudo can let you act as another user even if you don't know their password. It can be done as detailed in this answer:

- [sudo as another user with their environment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177011/200094)

Here is an example from the answer (granted on my single user system):

```
$ whoami
rick

$ sudo -i -u root whoami
root
```

So in your case use:

```
sudo -i -u usertofake install_something
```